# Почему не работает AES шифрования в PHP

Tags: php, aes

```
function encrypt($data)
    {
        $key = "1234567887654321"; 
        $iv = "1234567887654321";
        $base64_str = base64_encode(json_encode($data));
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($base64_str, "aes-128-cbc", $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }    


    
    $data = "Hello"; 
    $encrypt=encrypt($data);
    echo $encrypt;
```

Почему в итоге всегда возвращает null?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-error-string.php